# TextField message not sending from server to client and vice versa and getting weird output

Tags: java, swing, file, networking, awt

I am building a GUI based chat application using sockets and file i/o.
My idea on the process of this program is:

1. Launch ChatServer
2. Launch ChatClient
3. When both server & client are connected to each while clicking on connect button, they can start chatting.
4. Pressing "Enter"(from client) will send the texts from Text Field to the server chatWindow(i.e TextArea).
5. Client will update the Text Area appending the text received from server.

While I type any message and hitting enter the message is not going to server -> client and vice versa. The message is showing into the `chatWindow` (i.e `JTextArea`) of the same GUI which is weird. What will be the correct way to do it? I want read & write the streams after connecting to the network.

GUI is acting like below:

[image: Current GUI]

Here's the instance variables :

```
JPanel contentPane;
    JButton send;
    DataInputStream dis;
    DataOutputStream dos;
    ServerSocket server;
    Socket conn;
    JLabel attach = new JLabel("");
    JTextField t1 = new JTextField();
    JTextArea chatWindow = new JTextArea();
```

Here's my main :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {

                try {
                    ChatPage2 frame = new ChatPage2();
                    frame.setVisible(true);


                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

I have added actionListener event to the textfield and trying to append the text from textfield to the textarea called chatWindow :

```
t1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            String line = t1.getText();
            chatWindow.append(line + "\n");
            if ((evt.getSource() == line) && (t1.getText() != "")) {
                chatWindow.setText(chatWindow.getText() + '\n' + "ME:"
                        + t1.getText());
                try {
                    DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(
                            conn.getOutputStream());
                    dos.writeUTF(t1.getText());
                } catch (Exception e1) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(3000);
                        System.exit(0);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e2) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e2.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                t1.setText("");
            }   
        }   
        });
```

For Server connection below is the code I applied :

//connect is the event button... while clicking on connect button the network will get connected.

```
connect.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                try {
                    server=new ServerSocket(2020, 10, InetAddress.getLocalHost());
                    chatWindow.setText("Waiting for Client");
                } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }

                new Thread(()-> {
                    try {
                        conn=server.accept();
                        chatWindow.setText(chatWindow.getText() + '\n' + "Client Found");
                        //chatWindow.setText(chatWindow.getText() + '\n' + "Client Found");
                    } catch (IOException e1) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }


                    while (true) {
                        try {
                            DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
                            String string = dis.readUTF();
                            //string = br.readLine();
                            chatWindow.setText(chatWindow.getText() + '\n' + "Client:"
                                    + string);
                        } catch (IOException ioException) {
                            chatWindow.setText(chatWindow.getText() + '\n'
                                    + "Sorry, Cant send the message !");
                            try {
                                Thread.sleep(3000);
                                System.exit(0);
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }   
                        }
                    }
                }).start(); 


            }
        });
```

For Client connection I applied below code :

//connect is the event button... while clicking on connect button the network will get connected.

```
connect.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                new Thread(()-> {   
                try {
                    conn = new Socket(InetAddress.getLocalHost(),2020);
                    chatWindow.setText("Connected to SERVER");
                } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }




                    while (true) {
                        try {
                            DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
                            String string = dis.readUTF();
                            //string = br.readLine();
                            chatWindow.setText(chatWindow.getText() + '\n' + "Server:"
                                    + string);
                        } catch (IOException ioException) {
                            chatWindow.setText(chatWindow.getText() + '\n'
                                    + "Sorry, Cant send the message !");
                            try {
                                Thread.sleep(3000);
                                System.exit(0);
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }   
                        }

                    }

                }).start(); 

            }
        });
```

Comment: Ok.
Also do you have a question you want to ask?

Comment: `evt.getSource() == line` is wrong, the source of the event is not a `String` .

Comment: @Ben Yes buddy. While I type any message and hitting enter the message is not going to server -> client and vice versa. The message is showing into the chatWindow (i.e JTextArea) of the same GUI which is weird. Need a help on that.

Comment: @Berger What will be the correct way to do it? I want read & write the streams after connecting to the network.

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: It's solved. Thanks everyone.